# MySQL | Как добавить в таблицу строку не проверяя перед этим её

Tags: mysqli

Собственно вопрос в шапке

Имеется таблица, в которой уже есть данные, какое решение можно предложить, чтобы не брать все строки из бд и не сравнивать на наличие той, которую я хочу сейчас вписать.

Имеется таблица : 'users' => "admin";
При регистрации пользователя, я выбираю всех пользователей из таблицы вот таким образом

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '{$login}' LIMIT 1
```

И если мне SELECT возвращает не NULL , то такой человек уже есть, и его добавлять нельзя.

Но я где-то видел, что можно обойтись и в одном запросе это всё организовать, как быть?

Comment: сделать уникальный индекс по полю login, если его еще нет и использовать `insert ignore into users...` или `insert ... on duplicate key update`

Comment: так весь и прикол, в том что я знаю про уникальный индекс по полю логин, но есть запрос который проверяет значение из бд и если такого нет, то добавляет

Comment: ну так уберите этот запрос и используйте то, что я указал выше. insert ingore вставляет запись только тогда, когда такой нет

Comment: как будто любое другое решение не будет "выбирать все строки" (что бы это не значило), а определит необходимость вставки телепатическим путем

Comment: да наверное проще выбрать все строки и сделать сравнение, чем сейчас тр*хать себе мозги этой ерундой.